How do I link 3 animations made in 3 different scenes of the same character for Unity in NLA
I already have 3 FBX files. Idle, Speed walk and walk. I am a beginner and thats why I copied the character and pasted in to 3 scenes. I want to clarify that when I talk about scenes I mean new blender projects. If its possible I would like to use the FBX files.

You should do everything in one Blender file using the NLA editor rather than using 3 seperate .blend files. This is not a tutorial site but there are quite a few tutorials online, most using Mixamo FBX animations. Try this one for instance.

Thanks for replying! It means a lot. In retrospect I would have. Unfortunately when I imported the FBX files the rig was strange and when I used the rig  for all the animations some weird things started happening and the bones lined up. Possibly something to do with constraints or IK that gets applied. ????   All of the objects that were parented to the bones were showing up in the NLA despite them not having any keyframes. I think I will just use all 3 individually in unity. It's a bit of a disaster.  The tutorial was a great suggestion. Thanks for your time.

If the armatures are the same (have the same structure and bones including the naming) You can link the animation data and then use make single user so to effectively copy the animation from one to the other. You may need to move other keyframes out of the way on the timeline before that or the animations will get mixed up. Google "Blender copy animation to another object" and there are multiple in depth descriptions of the proces. The one on blendersecrets.org is clear.
